# boost::rational - prevent default reducing (i.e. 2/2 to 1/1)?

Tags: c++, boost, rational-number

In the boost::rational class, if I do

```
boost::rational<int> r(2,2);
std::cout << r << std::endl;
```

The result will be `1/1`.  Is there a way to keep this as `2/2` without having to write a wrapper around the rational class?  Ideally, I'd like this to apply to addition as well, so that something like

```
boost::rational<int> r(2,2);
boost::rational<int> s(2,2);
std::cout << r + s << std::endl;
```

would yield `4/2` instead of `2/1`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I doubt that any well-designed rational arithmetic library would allow this. Just keep the desired denominator around in your own code.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you describe the context where this is necessary?

Comment: What result would you expect from `1/6 + 1/10`? 4/15 or 16/60?

Comment: @interjay `8/30` obviously ;-)

Comment: The context would be representing musical time signatures, which don't reduce. Two measures of 4/4 combined together give one measure of 8/4.  I hadn't thought it through, though, and I see that for cases with different denominators there's no clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, by design:

> The final fundamental operation is normalizing a rational. This operation is performed whenever a rational is constructed (and assigned in place). All other operations are careful to maintain rationals in a normalized state. Normalization costs the equivalent of one gcd and two divisions.

from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/rational/rational.html